# Isolating the zinc core from the copper shell of a U.S. penny

Tags: solubility

I am a grad student who has a friend with a pretty nice personal lab, one thing I have always sought out to do as a chemist is to remove only the copper (and also obviously the copper oxide) from the outside of a penny. I know that a common experiment is dissolving the zinc core as I have done that many times for demonstrations but wanted to turn the tables. I have seem some things about using Potassium Cyanide but I feel like there is potentially a safer way that i’m just not thinking about. Any alternatives y’all can think of?

Comment: Good luck with that :/  Zn is *a lot* more reactive than Cu.

Comment: Cheat: electroplate Zn *onto* the copper cladding -- it will react as Zn (until it dissolves off). ;-)